# phoneFieldChanged' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8

'phoneFieldChanged' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

[image]

Comment: You forgot to post question...

Comment: How to solve this error

Comment: Probably you should post your code (as code not as screenshot). You have problem with `PhoneVerificationController` - I don't know anything about it. Is it your class? Or maybe you added it to your project somehow. If you want to get help - at least post important parts of your problem. I also hope that you know what means `internal protection level` - please check it out.

Comment: internal protection level strict the project to run in another system.I just want to solve the project and run it properly on device.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that you are incorrect. You can find more information on this topic - posted answer suggests it. When you get familiar with concept you should be ready to easily fix your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for guiding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is surprisingly descriptive here. Take a look at `PhoneVerificationController` definition. Most probably `phoneNumberField` property is specified with `internal` access level, which means it is accessible only within module where it is defined and most probably this is a 3rd party dependency since it's not accessible in your source code.

To solve this error you can:

1. Change access level to public
2. Take a closer look at documentation of `PhoneVerificationController` and find out which public API it has to address your specific use-case

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I will try to to figure out how to Change access level to public and private API